Is there any difference between the expressions "the second", "the minute" and "the moment"?
Of course the spelling and pronunciation is different but is there a difference in meaning or grammar?

"second" and "moment" are shorter periods than "minute". So if you say that something should be done the moment (or the second) that something else happens, you're saying that you should do it more quickly than if you say the minute that something else happens.
None of these should be taken literally, it's just an indication of how urgent the second action is.

"The minute you get there, I want you to phone me!", said my mother. I can't imagine that you could assign graduations of urgency by using 'second' (=1,000 milliseconds) or 'moment' (utterly immeasurable). The meaning is 'straight away!'.

They're both urgent, but if she said "the second" it still sounds more urgent. But sometimes it's just what you happen to have learned. Being too urgent can also sound overbearing.

Yes, and I have to agree that 'Call me the very instant that you hear anything!' sounds more urgent still. Possibly a physicist might say 'I want to know the nanosecond the baby is born!'.
